# how to create a delegate on target class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

First time posting here after years of lurking, thanks in advance for any help.

I am trying to create a delegate on an instance of a controller from within a static class, and I get the error:
"Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type."

The error occurs in the method GetReasonsForDeny, where I pass in the entity and typeof(HomeController).

My Code is here:

```
public class HomeController : Project.Web.Controllers.Base.Controller
{
    //Properties
    IUserRepository UserRepository { get; set; }

    //Constructor
    HomeController(IUserRepository userRepository)
        : Project.Web.Controllers.Base.Controller
    {
        UserRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public List<string> CanPerformAction(IEntity entity)
    {
        List<string> reasonsForDeny = new List<string>();
        TestEntity domainEntity = entity as TestEntity;

        if (domainEntity != null)
            VerifyRules(domainEntity, UserRepository, out reasonsForDeny);

        return reasonsForDeny;
    }
}

public static class ControllerActionHelper
{
    private static List<string> GetReasonsForDeny(IEntity entity, Type Controller)
    {
        List<string> reasonsForDeny = new List<string>();

        MethodInfo accessMethod = controller.GetMethod("CanPerformAction");
        if (accessMethod != null)
        {
            /***** Error Here ********/
            Func<IEntity, List<string>> accessDelegate = (Func<IEntity, List<string>>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<IEntity, List<string>>), controller, accessMethod);

            reasonsForDeny = accessDelegate(entity);
        }

        return reasonsForDeny
    }
}
```

I have also tried changing the delegate to be static by passing null into CreateDelegate as shown below, but if I do this then when CanPerformAction is called my UserRepository has a value of null.

```
// Before
Func<IEntity, List<string>> accessDelegate = (Func<IEntity, List<string>>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<IEntity, List<string>>), controller, accessMethod);

// After
Func<IEntity, List<string>> accessDelegate = (Func<IEntity, List<string>>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<IEntity, List<string>>), null, accessMethod);
```

Finally, I have tried creating a non-static class which would create the delegate, and then return it to the static class as shown below, but the non-static class gets the same error: "Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type."

```
public static class ControllerActionHelper
{
    private static List<string> GetReasonsForDeny(IEntity entity, Type Controller)
    {
        List<string> reasonsForDeny = new List<string>();

        MethodInfo accessMethod = controller.GetMethod("CanPerformAction");
        if (accessMethod != null)
        {
            var tempInstance = new foo();

            Func<IEntity, List<string>> accessDelegate = foo.MakeMyDelegatePlease(controller, accessMethod, entity);

            reasonsForDeny = accessDelegate(entity);
        }

        return reasonsForDeny
    }
}

public class foo
{
    public Func<IEntity, List<string>> MakeMyDelegatePlease(Type controller, MethodInfo accessMethod, IEntity entity)
    {
        /********* Error Here ************/
        Func<IEntity, List<string>> accessDelegate = (Func<IEntity, List<string>>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<IEntity, List<string>>), controller, accessMethod);

        return accessDelegate;
    }
}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Very well-written first question. We need more good ASP.Net MVC questions; the patterns are new to many people and the platform is rapidly maturing.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass in the controller instance to `GetReasonsForDeny`, not just it's type, since `CanPerformAction` is a method on a particular instance of HomeController.

```
private static List<string> GetReasonsForDeny(IEntity entity, object controller)
{
    List<string> reasonsForDeny = new List<string>();

    MethodInfo accessMethod = controller.GetType().GetMethod("CanPerformAction");
    if (accessMethod != null)
    {
        /***** Error Here ********/
        Func<IEntity, List<string>> accessDelegate = (Func<IEntity, List<string>>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<IEntity, List<string>>), controller, accessMethod);

        reasonsForDeny = accessDelegate(entity);
    }

    return reasonsForDeny
}
```

On a slightly unrelated note though, you'd make life a lot easier for yourself if you used an interface to strongly type this stuff so that you don't need to use reflection at all

e.g.

```
interface ICanPerformAction
{
    List<string> CanPerformAction(IEntity entity);
}

public class HomeController : Project.Web.Controllers.Base.Controller, ICanPerformAction
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the advice. I was worried that I would have to pass in the controller, as I'm dealing with a rather complex project and I'm pretty sure I will have to pass the controller through 3-6 other methods before it gets to the helper method that is responsible for evaluating the action. Also, I greatly simplified the method CanPerformAction on the controller, in reality the method starts with the word Can, followed by a method name that is identical to a controller action attribute, which we use reflection for to find all available methods and restrict access to. Thanks again.

Comment: Unfortunately, you don't have much choice here.. The main problem is that the method is referring to a particular property on an instance of this class (in your example it's UserRepository). Without passing in the instance, it can't know which of potentially many UserRepositories to use. If CanPerformAction were static, this wouldn't be a problem